# Calculate digits of $\pi$ without needing to reuse them

Tags: algorithms, irrational-numbers, pi

I am looking for some algorithms that can calculate the digits of $\pi$ without needing to reuse previous digits. I would like to find the most simple and fast algorithms possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up "spigot algorithm"

Comment: In particular, such algorithms are known for the 'binary digits' of $\pi$, but not for its decimal expansion.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Well, I will be implementing one go these algorithms in a program, so binary is not an issue.

Comment: @Progo But to what purpose?  What will you be displaying, and what will you be using?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Umm... I would be displaying the digits of pi. It is easy to convert binary to decimal. When you say, "will you be using?" you mean what programming language, I will be using C++ or C#.

Comment: No, but the point is that to convert the digits from binary to decimal you need _all_ the binary digits, so spigot-style algorithms (which let you answer e.g. 'what is the billionth digit of pi?' without needing to look at all the digits up to that point) aren't particularly useful for what you're doing.  It's much more efficient just to generate the full  high-precision value in the first place via any of the classic quickly-convergent approximation algorithms rather than generating digits one by one with a spigot algorithm.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ok, I see your point, perhaps I should have explained myself better. In most pi calculation programs, the digits of pi are written to a file. My program would write the binary digits to a file. Then, once all the digits have been calculated, the program would go back and convert the file into decimal.